# Postman AssertionError expected: 'value' to equal value

Tags: javascript, postman

ISSUE:
In Postman I'm running a POST request and trying to assert what I receive in my response body to what is being passed via a CSV file.

The CSV file contains three columns: employee_name, employee_salary, and employee_age. All are set as general for formatting (the default).

The assert works fine for employee_name but when I try to do this for employee_age and employee_salary I get an error like this: 
AssertionError: expected '35' to equal 35

[Here](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/) is the API I'm using.

WHAT I'VE TRIED:
I've tried setting the format of the age and salary cells in the CSV file to text and to number to no avail.

CODE:

```
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();

    pm.test("Verify name", function() {
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.name).to.equal(pm.iterationData.get("employee_name"));
    });

    pm.test("Verify age", function() {
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.age).to.equal(pm.iterationData.get("employee_age"));
    });

    pm.test("Verify salary", function() {
        pm.expect(jsonData.data.salary).to.equal(pm.iterationData.get("employee_salary"));
    });
```

Thanks for any help!

Best,
Jason

Comment: Looks like it is failing because '35' is a string, and 35 is a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying the match a `string` with an `Integer` so you could wrap the values from the data file with `parseInt()`.

For example, the age would be like this:

`pm.expect(jsonData.data.age).to.equal(parseInt(pm.iterationData.get("employee_age")))`

Comment: I had to use the parseInt on the jsonData.data.age instead as that was the part that was a string but this solution worked! Thanks so much for your help :).

Comment: Ah that's makes sense. It's was one of the other  I couldn't see your response body so I took a guess 